# Identify mouse click unity3d

Tags: c#, unity

I have a 3 fbx models. When i click on the first object it should displays its name of the gameobject in a label and clear the label  when click on another object.
How to display the name of the gameobject in a label.I dont know how it identifies the click and how to get the name of that object display in label.

```
 void Start () {
    gui.enabled = true;
    labelfont=new GUIStyle();
    labelfont.fontSize=18;
    labelfont.normal.textColor=Color.white;

}
void OnMouseEnter () {
    //code I have so far
    Debug.Log ("nameee" + gameObject.name);

if (gameObject.name == "venacava") 
    {
      gui.text = "";
     gui.text = "venacava";
  displaymessage = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: With magic. Flagging this as unclear what you're asking. Show some examples of what you tried, and maybe we can help you from there.

Comment: In the future break your question into smaller parts. Selecting the model is one, highlighting the model is another and displaying text on screen is another.

Comment: I removed the additional questions from your post. Do not edit your question when the original question is answered. Ask a separate question for each issue you're having.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to select objects in Unity, you need to add [colliders](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) to your objects. Just dragging the model into the scene will not automatically add a collider. For each game object you want to interact with, select it in the Hierarchy and add a [MeshCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) using the Inspector.

Now, create a script that will display interact with the objects, something like Highlighter. In the Highlighter script, you can implement the method [`OnMouseDown`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html). This method is activated when the user left clicks an object in the scene. Inside this method you make whatever changes you like to the selected objects.

Comment: Comments are not a discussion area. If you have further questions ask them as questions on the site. Please refer to the [help] to learn how to use this site.